# Can I base a branch on a different one from the current?

Tags: git, merge, branch

I'm sure the question doesn't help much.

So I have `dev` and `uat` branches. The `uat` itself was once created from `dev`. A while ago I needed to add a patch, so I created another branch called `connection-timeout`. But only after lots of work and commits on that branch and merging it to `uat` I realized that I created it from `uat` instead of the `dev` branch. Now I want to merge it (the connection-timout branch) to `dev`, but I want to avoid commits that came from `uat`. Is it possible to make so that the `connection-timout` branch be based on the `dev`?

Comment: You want to merge UAT into dev _without_ any of its commits?

Comment: No, I want to merge connection-timout branch into dev.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will want to `git rebase` your `connection-timeout` branch on `dev`.

Right now your graph may look like this:

```
dev * - - * - - * - - * - - *
      \ 
uat    \- * - - * - - * - - *
                       \
connection-timeout      \ - * - - * - - *
```

If you do the following:

```
git checkout connection-timeout

git rebase dev
```

You will end up with this instead:

```
connection-timeout            / - * - - * - - *
                             /
dev * - - * - - * - - * - - *
      \ 
uat    \- * - - * - - * - - *
```

You can then reset `uat` to the state it had before merging.

**Attention**: If you already pushed your `connection-timeout` to a remote, you will have to use

```
git push --force
```

As you are rewriting history. This may cause issues if other people are working on this branch as their history will now be inconsistent with the remote.

Comment: Thanks for that. I did just what you suggested.